# "Cannot find namespace" only during ng test

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular-cli, adal

I'm assuming/feel sure that I'm just missing something very minor.  There is an adal.ts file that contains an adal namespace. (this is local to my project)  For some reason this file doesn't automatically load into the tests like it does when i run ng serve??

I am implementing adal-angular and it is working correctly, except when I run the unit tests, I get a "Cannot find namepsace 'adal'".

How do I get the namespace to be found and/or mocked in the unit tests??

I followed this example, but the unit tests also do not seem to work:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/using-adal-js-with-angular4/

There has to be a way to mock / stub out the adal namespace?
Or do I just need to include adal.js or adal.ts in the tests somehow...
Again, it works when building just not on tests.

I guess I will have to go back to @types/adal even tho it recommends @types/adal-angular

Comment: Do you have a `tsconfig.spec.json` file? If so check to see if that `typeRoots` matches that of the `tsconfig.app.json` file (if you have one of those too). Let me know if this fixes it or if these files are different/exist.

Comment: those files do exist..  however, neither of them have anything to do with Adal in them

Comment: ill attempt to add adal to the spec version to test though

Comment: i dont think that worked..  so I have a /node_modules/@types/adal-angular folder..  so i added "adal-angular" to the types array in the .spec.json file..  does that sound correct?

Comment: @Igor any other ideas though?  here is something interesting.  the namespace is just an adal.ts file local to my project. however it does seem like that should be a "type".   just confused why I cannot get ANY of the tests to run